# Formula that will sum one column on condition of another column

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a formula that will sum up one column, on certain conditions of another column. For example, if column a contains letters "y" and "z," and only select rows in column b have numbers in them, I need a formula that will only count the sum of column b, that have letter a in column z. For example, in the screen shot, I'd like a formula that will automatically sum for "y" and "z":

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3BQam.png)
[image: Example]

Comment: simply try `SUMIFS()`like `=SUMIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,"y")` for `y`... but if you only want to count them, better use `COUNTIF()`

Comment: So, problem is solved? or still need help?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use sumif formula:
In B10 cell

```
  =SUMIF(A2:A10,"z",B2:B10)
```

In B11 cell

```
  =SUMIF(A2:A10,"y",B2:B10)
```

If you have many so many data and item then use tricky formula above mentioned in comment by @pnuts

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying the IF statements, and then sum inside parenthesis! I figured it was maybe a case where I was over complicating things!